# Difference between sending a MailMessage to an Exchange Server and sending to an SMTP server

Tags: c#, exchange-server, smtpclient, exchangewebservices

I am trying to use the [MailMessage class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t22a8ww%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to construct e-mail messages that are transmitted to an SMTP server for delivery using the SmtpClient class. 
My email is configured on outlook through an exchange server.
I had the following doubts with regards to the above implementation:

1) What is the difference between an Exchange Server and a SMTP server?

2) In my case, my outlook is configured on an exchange server using my credentials.How do I  find the SMTP address so that i am able to implement the MailMessage Class?

3) Any ideas of sending emails through the application based on the exchange server if the above implementation technique is not feasible?

I am using Visual studio 2008, framework 3.5 SP1, working on winforms application with C# as the language. Please help me clear my doubts.

**EDIT**

I am using the following code. It doesn't throw any error, neither does it work. I am trying to send and email to myself bu to no avail

```
public static void CreateMessageWithAttachment(string server)
    {
        // Specify the file to be attached and sent.
        // This example assumes that a file named Data.xls exists in the
        // current working directory.
        string file = "data.xls";
        // Create a message and set up the recipients.
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
           "ben@contoso.com",
           "ben@contoso.com",
           "Quarterly data report.",
           "See the attached spreadsheet.");

        // Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
        Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        // Add time stamp information for the file.
        ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
        disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
        disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
        disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
        // Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
        message.Attachments.Add(data);

        //Send the message.
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
        // Add credentials if the SMTP server requires them.
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

  try {
          client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
          Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateMessageWithAttachment(): {0}", 
                ex.ToString() );              
        }

        data.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: @Phoenix: contoso.com is an example domain. Those emails aren't real. No need to munge them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) What is the difference between an Exchange Server and a SMTP server?

Exchange server contains more stuff.

> 2) In my case, my outlook is configured on an exchange server using my credentials.How do I find the SMTP address so that i am able to implement the MailMessage Class?

Outlook -> Tools -> Accounts -> Edit account.

It's the same address as the exchange server. Port 25 is the standard SMTP port.
Exchange might need authentication.

> 3) Any ideas of sending emails through the application based on the exchange server if the above implementation technique is not feasible?

You can't just use `MailMessage`, you'll need `SmtpClient` too.

Example using Exchange: [Getting a sent MailMessage into the "Sent Folder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471218/getting-a-sent-mailmessage-into-the-sent-folder)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I have updated my question with the code that I am using to attain the solution. Please check if you can figure out any errors in my code

Comment: 1. Have you tried without the attachment? 2. Are you sure that you are using the correct server address? 3) Have you tried by manually specify the credentials?

Comment: The answer to all your questions is yes. However, my exchange server address for example is abcd.abc.company.com which doesn't work. So right now I have changed it to abcd.abc.company.com:25, to specify the SMTP portnumber. but that doesnt work as well.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Connection failed. I guess that I have to figure out the right smtp address.. Thanks man for your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

[SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) is a protocol, a set of rules governing communication between two systems.  This protocol defines the rules for sending mail.

An SMTP server is a component (mostly software) that uses this protocol to send mail.

MS Exchange uses SMTP to send mail, but it also governs users and mailboxes for users on a domain.