# Convert MailMessage to Raw text

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any easy way to convert a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage object to the raw mail message text, like when you open a eml file in notepad.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's the same solution, but as an extension method to `MailMessage`.

Some of the reflection overhead is minimized by grabbing the `ConstructorInfo` and `MethodInfo` members once in the static context.

```
/// <summary>
/// Uses reflection to get the raw content out of a MailMessage.
/// </summary>
public static class MailMessageExtensions
{
    private static readonly BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    private static readonly Type MailWriter = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");
    private static readonly ConstructorInfo MailWriterConstructor = MailWriter.GetConstructor(Flags, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);
    private static readonly MethodInfo CloseMethod = MailWriter.GetMethod("Close", Flags);
    private static readonly MethodInfo SendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", Flags);

    /// <summary>
    /// A little hack to determine the number of parameters that we
    /// need to pass to the SaveMethod.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly bool IsRunningInDotNetFourPointFive = SendMethod.GetParameters().Length == 3;

    /// <summary>
    /// The raw contents of this MailMessage as a MemoryStream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="self">The caller.</param>
    /// <returns>A MemoryStream with the raw contents of this MailMessage.</returns>
    public static MemoryStream RawMessage(this MailMessage self)
    {
        var result = new MemoryStream();
        var mailWriter = MailWriterConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { result });
        SendMethod.Invoke(self, Flags, null, IsRunningInDotNetFourPointFive ? new[] { mailWriter, true, true } : new[] { mailWriter, true }, null);
        result = new MemoryStream(result.ToArray());
        CloseMethod.Invoke(mailWriter, Flags, null, new object[] { }, null);
        return result;
    }
}
```

To grab the underlying `MemoryStream`:

```
var email = new MailMessage();
using (var m = email.RawMessage()) {
    // do something with the raw message
}
```

Comment: Does this work (with the additional parameter for `Send`) in .NET 4.5 on your PC? I had to copy the content of `result` to another `MemoryStream` before calling `CloseMethod`, because the current implementation will actually close the underlying stream.

Comment: This works for .NET 4.0 -- I haven't tried it in 4.5. I'd be happy to include your update in my answer (and give you credit, of course).

Comment: Yes, it should work like that, but I also added a check for .NET 4.5. I could update the answer with what works, if that's okay with you?

Comment: FYI, I noticed that the Send method actually strips out the BCC since it's prepping it for sending. If you are just going to pass this to Amazon SES or some other type of service, that isn't what you want. I ended up just manually creating the MIME string instead.

Comment: @allonhadaya, it seems like the answer does not return the [MIME encoded-word syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) for non-ASCII characters?

Comment: @Gan, very curious... This just leverages the internal message making mechanism. Have you set all the necessary encoding properties on MailMessage? Search for encoding on this page to see them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @allonhadaya, yes I did set all the encoding related properties. After I call the RawMessage method, I look into the debug watch window, those non-ascii characters are still showing as they are, not MIME encoded. The only way I managed to see the MIME encoded message is by sending it to an SMTP server and view the .eml file manually. Can you try your solution with non-ascii characters (e.g. Chinese, Japanese)?

Comment: @Gan Give this a shot if you have the time. I'd be interested in how it turns out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028757/subject-encoding-on-smtpclient-mailmessage

Answer (score 9):

I've implemented logic in [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) to allow you to cast a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage into a [MimeKit.MimeMessage](http://jstedfast.github.io/MimeKit/docs/MimeKit/MimeMessage.html#M%3aMimeKit.MimeMessage.op_Explicit%28System.Net.Mail.MailMessage%29~MimeKit.MimeMessage). Once you do that, you can simply write the message to a stream:

```
var message = (MimeMessage) CreateSystemNetMailMessage ();
using (var stream = File.Create ("C:\\message.eml"))
    message.WriteTo (stream);
```

This does not require reflecting into internal methods which means that it isn't dependent on the runtime, making it far more portable that the other answers given so far.

Comment: I noticed that the reflection method does not get my SubjectEncoding (UTF8) for sending via Amazon SES right. Mimekit does. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Glad MimeKit has been helpful!

Comment: Looks like you're [just mapping by hand](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/1ea79dddc1a1dd96890e2f3fe2395232f8165a4c/MimeKit/MimeMessage.cs#L1951), so to speak, right? Not that that's horribly bad or a deal breaker, but it's theoretically lossy if I'm not missing something. (??) (Trying to adapt my code to MonoMac now, and was about to give up & do a mapping-by-hand myself.)

Comment: Yes, it's just mapping by hand but it should be complete. Obviously mapping is not ideal as a long-term solution and so I would recommend using MimeKit to construct the message as the long-term solution, but the mapping method is useful if you are incrementally porting your S.N.Mail code in the short-term... if that makes sense.

Comment: Oh, and if you need SMTP, I have a library called [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) which adds SMTP, POP3 and IMAP support on top of MimeKit.

Answer (score 2):

The code I've seen to do this relies on reflection. I adapted the samples found online to create this method:

```
    private static MemoryStream ConvertMailMessageToMemoryStream(MailMessage message)
    {
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        Assembly assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        Type mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");
        ConstructorInfo mailWriterContructor = mailWriterType.GetConstructor(flags, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);
        object mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { stream });
        MethodInfo sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", flags);
        sendMethod.Invoke(message, flags, null, new[] { mailWriter, true }, null);
        MethodInfo closeMethod = mailWriter.GetType().GetMethod("Close", flags);                
        closeMethod.Invoke(mailWriter, flags, null, new object[] { }, null);
        return stream;
    }
```

You can then convert the `MemoryStream` to a string or whatever you need.

Update: A method signature has changed in .NET 4.5, which breaks the above:
[Getting System.Net.Mail.MailMessage as a MemoryStream in .NET 4.5 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595440/getting-system-net-mail-mailmessage-as-a-memorystream-in-net-4-5-beta)

Answer (score 0):

Fixing @allonhadaya's answer for .NET 8:

```
/// <summary>
/// Uses reflection to get the raw content out of a MailMessage.
/// </summary>
public static class MailMessageExtensions
{
    private static readonly BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    private static readonly Type? MailWriter = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");
    private static readonly ConstructorInfo? MailWriterConstructor = MailWriter?.GetConstructor(Flags, null, new[] { typeof(Stream), typeof(bool) }, null);
    private static readonly MethodInfo? CloseMethod = MailWriter?.GetMethod("Close", Flags);
    private static readonly MethodInfo? SendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", Flags);

    /// <summary>
    /// A little hack to determine the number of parameters that we
    /// need to pass to the SaveMethod.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly bool IsRunningInDotNetFourPointFive = SendMethod?.GetParameters().Length == 3;

    /// <summary>
    /// The raw contents of this MailMessage as a MemoryStream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="self">The caller.</param>
    /// <returns>A MemoryStream with the raw contents of this MailMessage.</returns>
    public static MemoryStream RawMessage(this MailMessage self)
    {
        var result = new MemoryStream();
        var mailWriter = MailWriterConstructor?.Invoke([result, false]);
        _ = mailWriter ?? throw new ApplicationException("Could not create a new MailWriter");
        _ = SendMethod ?? throw new ApplicationException("Could not find the SendMethod");
        SendMethod?.Invoke(self, Flags, null, IsRunningInDotNetFourPointFive ? new[] { mailWriter, true, true } : new[] { mailWriter, true }, null);
        result = new MemoryStream(result.ToArray());
        _ = CloseMethod ?? throw new ApplicationException("Could not find the CloseMethod");
        CloseMethod?.Invoke(mailWriter, Flags, null, [], null);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Changed is that the internal `MailWriter` constructor was changed to take one more `bool encodeForTransport` parameter (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73398685/2003763).

Answer (score -1):

```cs
byte[] allBytes = new byte[attachment.ContentStream.Length];
int bytesRead = attachment.ContentStream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)attachment.ContentStream.Length);
Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
String contenidoCorreo = encoding.GetString(allBytes);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answer really adds anything without explanation.