# Plain text mime email to MailMessage

Tags: c#, email, smtp, mime, mailmessage

I found this thread: [Convert MailMessage to Raw text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515457/convert-mailmessage-to-raw-text)

Its about taking a MailMessage and converting it to raw text ready for sending.

Is their a way to convert that raw text back into a MailMessage?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's BCL does not include any way of doing it, but you can use a library such as [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) (NuGet package [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MimeKit/)) to parse the message.

Comment: Cool, if you have any questions, let me know. I've also got a library called [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) for doing SMTP, POP3, and/or IMAP.