# GMail Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 The message contains an unauthorized custom from address because the

Tags: c#, email, gmail

Been sending emails from my C# application for awhile now.  But tried tonight, and its not working.  Been googling but have to come across anything anything with the exception message I am getting.

Exception: `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException`

Message: `Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 The message contains an unauthorized custom from address because the` <--- this is where the message ends, not much help.

```
MailMessage _Mail;
_Mail = new MailMessage("myEmailAddress@gmail.com", "friendsEmail@elseWhere.com");
_Mail.Subject = "Subject";
_Mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

// Create HTML body  
var htmlBody = "...";

_Mail.Body = htmlBody;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 587;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myEmailAddress@gmail.com","password");
client.Send(_Mail);
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Edit: I am using .Net 3.5

Comment: Get the full text of the email and add it to your question (edit any real email addresses).  To learn how, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515457/convert-mailmessage-to-raw-text

Comment: @EricJ. I tried your suggestion, but I get a `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled` Exception seems to be coming from `SendMethod.Invoke` call in the `RawMessage` method

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems the code in that answer targeted .NET 4.0.  Can you write a simple test program with your sending code and the reflection code targeting .NET 4.0?

Comment: @EricJ. It seems to be working again. And all I did was nothing... must have been an issue on Gmail's side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my C# application is working again.  It must have been a problem on Gmail side.  It would be insightful if someone can explain the reason.