# GetConstructor() method returning null value in .Net 6 but the same returning values in .Net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am trying to save the mailmessage in file. So i have used below code to save the mailmessage in file. the same code working in .Net core 3.1 but it's throwing error on .Net 6.

**Error Info:**
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Its happening because for GetConstructor() method returning null value

**Please find the snippet of code:**

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
            Type _mailWriterType =
              assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");

            using (FileStream _fileStream =
                   new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                // Get reflection info for MailWriter contructor
                ConstructorInfo _mailWriterContructor =
                    _mailWriterType.GetConstructor(
                        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                        null,
                        CallingConventions.HasThis,
                        new Type[] { typeof(Stream) },
                        null);

                // Construct MailWriter object with our FileStream
                object _mailWriter =
                  _mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { _fileStream });

                // Get reflection info for Send() method on MailMessage
                MethodInfo _sendMethod =
                    typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod(
                        "Send",
                        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

                // Call method passing in MailWriter
                _sendMethod.Invoke(
                    Message,
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                    null,
                    new object[] { _mailWriter, true, true },
                    null);

                // Finally get reflection info for Close() method on our MailWriter
                MethodInfo _closeMethod =
                    _mailWriter.GetType().GetMethod(
                        "Close",
                        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

                // Call close method
                _closeMethod.Invoke(
                    _mailWriter,
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                    null,
                    new object[] { },
                    null);
            }
```

Comment: That would suggest that the implementation of the type you're working with has changed and there is no longer a constructor that matches the specified criteria. You could call `GetConstructors` in both versions and see what differences there are, then change your criteria for .NET 6 to get an appropriate available constructor. That `MailWriter` class is declared `internal` and they are less shy about changing the interface of such types because no one is supposed to be using them outside the team that is making the change.

Comment: What would be the point of this whole messy code using reflection? Why not use the class directly?

Comment: Based on what @Charlieface is telling us below, you should get the constructor as follows: ConstructorInfo _mailWriterContructor =
                    _mailWriterType.GetConstructor(
                        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                        null,
                        CallingConventions.HasThis,
                        new Type[] { typeof(Stream), typeof(Boolean) },
                        null);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implementation of this *internal* class has changed, which shouldn't surprise you as it's internal and not documented, and therefore subject to change at any time (this includes minor builds, not just major version changes).

[The code used to have](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c788aa1ba77901856cc8b28056a85619c8d9a3ed/src/libraries/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/MailWriter.cs#L18)

```cs
        internal MailWriter(Stream stream)
            : base(stream, true)
        // This is the only stream that should encoding leading dots on a line.
        // This way it is done message wide and only once.
        {
        }
```

[Now it has](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/197ba91a4af0fcbb73b06197891eed8ccb609e7f/src/libraries/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/MailWriter.cs#L18)

```cs
        internal MailWriter(Stream stream, bool encodeForTransport)
            : base(stream, encodeForTransport)
        // This is the only stream that should encoding leading dots on a line.
        // This way it is done message wide and only once.
        {
        }
```

It changed in [this GitHub pull](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/e29bcf9c18235b32a1b7f33097c54877979f5ebf)

Comment: Great research! Thanks!